# Passing user context to from impersonated thread to outproc COM object

Tags: com

I am writing a CPP program on windows 2k3 where i want to achieve the following thing.

Pass the user context from the impersonated thread to a outproc COM component.

Steps what i m trying in details are:
1) Start an execution of exe with user USR1
2) Impersonate the current thread with USR2
3) Initiate a API on outproc COM object.
   And this COM object should run with USR2

What is happening:
on 3rd step, COM object is getting started with USR1 only.

Can anybody help me in passing the user context to COM object.

Thanks in advance,
Thumbeti

Answer (score 2):

To have the server impersonate USR2, you have to use [cloaking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246058.aspx). To enable cloaking, you either have to call [CoInitializeSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693736(VS.85).aspx) or [CoSetProxyBlanket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692692.aspx).

Comment: +1 since the OP apparently never did this. And now his thank you to you has been deleted. ;)